# Tomcat 9 not working with Java 10 on Ubuntu

Tags: java, apache, ubuntu, tomcat, server

I have downloaded Java 10 with this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java10-installer
sudo apt-get install oracle-java10-set-default
```

It is installed successfully since I can see the Java version through `java -version`

But when I change in `tomcat.service` file the

```
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-10-oracle/
```

I can't run anymore Tomcat. However, it works with Java 8 that has been installed through `sudo apt-get install default-jdk` command:

```
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre
```

Comment: have you noticed the path ends are differents?

Comment: @jhamon Yes, to mention that there is no 'jre' folder inside Java 10.

Comment: Why are you using that path? You installed the official java by oracle, why are you pointing to openjdk?

Comment: @BackSlash It was like that always in tomcat so I just thought that I have to change the JAVA_HOME. Are you saying that I shouldn't use the JAVA_HOME at all in tomcat.service?

Comment: Does `java -version` from command line work?

Comment: @rustyx Yes it does

Comment: @J.Doe You should use a Java home which points to the correct java installation. `oracle-java10-installer` does not install in `java-10-openjdk-amd64`. What is the output of `which java`?

Comment: @BackSlash Here it has I changed it, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I suggest to go with Java 8 or 9. Even if Tomcat says that Tomcat 9 can support Java 8 and later version is better to go stable instead of the las JRE.

From [Tomcat site](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html):

> Users were successfully running Tomcat 8 on Java 8 many months before
>   the first stable Java 8 release. However, users of early access builds
>   should be aware of the following:
>
> It is not unusual for the initial early access builds to contain bugs
>   that can cause problems for web applications running on Tomcat.
>
> If the new Java version introduces new language features then the default JSP
>   compiler may not support them immediately. Switching the JSP compiler
>   to javac may enable these new language features to be used in JSPs.
>
> If you do discover an problem using a Java early access build, please ask
>   for help. The Tomcat user's mailing list is probably the best place to
>   start.